# GoTo(basic) program

Tags: python, python-3.x, goto

I'm doing some tutorials online, and I'm stuck with an exercise :Write a function getBASIC() which takes no arguments, and does the following: it should keep reading lines from input using a while loop; when it reaches the end it should return the whole program in the form of a list of strings. Example of list of strings:

```
5 GOTO 30
10 GOTO 20
20 GOTO 10
30 GOTO 40
40 END
```

I wrote a program, but it doesn't work, however I will post it too:

```
def getBASIC():
    L=[]
    while "END" not in L:
        L.append(str(input()))
        if str(input()).endswith("END"):
            break
    return L
```

Also I notice you that I'm not allowed to use IS or RECURSION .

Comment: where does input() come from?
your indentation is wrong here.
sounds like homework.

Comment: What part of it doesn't work? What's the output?

Comment: @Lanaru It doesn't shows me the output, but the grader says:Error: list getBASIC() has wrong length 1, expected 2

Comment: @Inbar Rose the input is from the grader, and its on the form ^

Comment: @Reginald what is grader? where does it come from? what form?

Comment: @Inbar Rose A program, a machine, a robot, a software.He checks the code if is corect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
def get_basic():
    L = []
    while True:
        line = str( input() )
        L.append( line )
        if "END" in line:
            break
    return L
```

Comment: I get the input from myself, and it's in the form ^, thanks for your answer. ^ means look up.

Comment: it is a Python 3 code (`input()` is the same as `raw_input()` in Python 2). Remove unnecessary `str()`.

Comment: I think he means that he's not actually using Python's builtin `input` function, but it's a placeholder for something else on here.

Answer (score 4):

There are several errors:

- you call `input()` twice without appending it to the list the second time
- `'END' in L` determines whether there is `'END'` (whole) line in the list `L` (there isn't)

Note: `input()`already returns a `str` object; you don't need to call `str()` on its returned value.

To read input until you've got empty line you could:

```
def getBASIC():
    return list(iter(input, ''))
```

Or to read until `END` is encountered at the end of line:

```
def getBASIC():
    L = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        L.append(line)
        if line.endswith("END"):
           break #NOTE: it doesn't break even if `line` is empty
    return L
```

Answer (score 2):

Back when I was learning Pascal, we used a priming read for loops that needed at least one iteration.  This still works well in Python (I prefer it to a `while True / break` loop).

By simply testing the last line in the list (rather than the last line read) we eliminate the need for a variable to store the input and can combine the reading and appending operations.

```
def getBASIC():
    lines = [input("]")]    # use Applesoft BASIC prompt  :-)
    while not lines[-1].upper().rstrip().endswith("END"):
        lines.append(input("]"))
    return lines
```

Comment: there is Python 3 tag in the question (there is no `raw_input()` in Python 3). Though the tag might be an error.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. Fixed. @Reginald: `raw_input()` is what `input()` used to be called in older Pythons (`input()` did something very different).

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. input() function takes string from standard input and tries to execute it as a python source coode. raw_input() will return a string as expected.
2. You use `input()` 2 time inside a loop. That means you await two string to be input inside one cycle iteration. You don't need last condition (if statement) inside your while loop. It'll end up when "END" is encountered in **L**.

The next code should do the job:

```
def getBASIC():
    L=[]
    while True:
        inp = raw_input()
        L.append(inp)
        if inp.endswith('END'):
            break
    return L
```

Comment: "END" will never be in L. because L is a list of the lines, the line that contains "END" is `40 END` which means you should have to check it "40 END" is in L.

Comment: Yeah, True, I've edited my answer after topic-starter edited task conditions.

Comment: Wath do you mean with:if not inp in ('IS', 'RECURSION'):

Comment: @Reginald, I just misunderstood last topic sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the following problems.

1. "`while "END" not in L`" will not work if your input is "40 END"
2. In Python 2.7, "`input()`" is equivalent to "`eval(raw_input()))`". So, Python is trying to evaluate the "GOTO" statements.
3. "`if str(input()).endswith("END"):`" does not append input to L

So, here is an updated version of your function:

```
def getBASIC():
    L = []
    while True:
        # Grab input
        L.append(str(raw_input()))

        # Check if last input ends with "END"
        if L[-1].endswith("END"):
            break
    return L
```